# Ambiguous Invocation on WhenActivated

Tags: c#, reactiveui, avalonia

I have a viewmodel where I'm trying to use `WhenActivated` to dispose:

```cs
    this.WhenActivated(disposables => 
    {
                       this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Selected)
                        .WhereNotNull()
                        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                        .Do(x => _logger.LogInformation($"selected {x?.Name}"))
                        .Subscribe(x => process(x))
                        .DisposeWith(disposables);
    });
```

And I get the error:

> MyViewModel.cs(59, 22): [CS0121] The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Reactive.Disposables.DisposableMixins.DisposeWith(T, System.Reactive.Disposables.CompositeDisposable)' and 'Avalonia.Controls.Mixins.DisposableMixin.DisposeWith(T, System.Reactive.Disposables.CompositeDisposable)'

Comment: Well, which of those extension methods did you expect to call? Perhaps you should remove a `using` directive for either `System.Reactive.Disposables` or `Avalonia.Controls.Mixins`? (If only one of those namespaces is imported, the call won't be ambiguous.)

Comment: @JonSkeet intended to use the former, but I realize I was focusing on looking in the ViewForMixins extensions provided by ReactiveUI for the correct method as indicated by the intellisense and not reading the error message properly.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to understand that comment... but this is a good example of why a [mcve] is useful, including what you *expect* to happen.